# Latest German dictionary pattern

Tags: hyphenation, german, pattern, dictionaries, format

I have included the format file latest German pattern from:
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/language/hyphenation/dehyph-exptl?lang=en

I have generated 45 German words in InDesign (using Duden Dictionary) and LaTeX. Only very few differences found.

**For example:**
Duden dictionary from InDesign produces the below patterns:

**Expected:**

```
kons-t-ruk-ti-ons-be-dingt 

pro-gramm-un-be-ein-uss-ba-ren
```

**But LaTeX produced as below:**

```
kon-struk-ti-ons-be-dingt

pro-gramm-un-beei-nuss-ba-ren
```

I need to match hyphenation using the Duden German dictionary pattern.
We are unable to judge how much words have differences.
Is the Duden dictionary pattern available in the LaTeX platform?
Kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: you can always declare exception rules, but `kons-t-ruk-ti-ons-be-dingt` looks wrong, and I have no idea what `programmunbeeinussbaren` should mean.

Comment: Even [Duden recommends](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/konstruktionsbedingt) kon|struk|ti|ons|be|dingt. Although, it shows *all* possibilities with kon|s|t|ruk|… I expect this to mean `kon-struk` as well as `kons-truk`  and *not* `kons-t-ruk`. After all `t` is not a syllable (and you won't even have a line width that would make a single `t` necessary anyway). From an etymologically point of view I'd recommend `kon-struk` as well (con = together, struere = to build).